# file not found compile_coref_data.sh

Tags: bash, allennlp

I'm not sure what's going on in [this](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/master/scripts/compile_coref_data.sh) script which is meant to download and compile some data. The download works for me but then I get an error "file not found". Should I have downloaded some other data beforehand?

The data is not really important to me. However, if anyone happens to know what's going on, I'm curious. Thanks in advance!

Last couple of logging messages:

```
...
reference-coreference-scorers/v8.01/test/DataFiles/TC-N-6.response
reference-coreference-scorers/v8.01/test/DataFiles/TC-N.key
reference-coreference-scorers/v8.01/test/test.pl
reference-coreference-scorers/v8.01/test/TestCases.README
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

could not find the gold parse [./data/files/data/arabic/annotations/nw/ann/02/ann_0283.parse] in the ontonotes distributi

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cat: 'conll-2012/v0/data/development/data/english/annotations/*/*/*/*.v0_gold_conll': No such file or directory
cat: 'conll-2012/v0/data/train/data/english/annotations/*/*/*/*.v0_gold_conll': No such file or directory
cat: 'conll-2012/v0/data/test/data/english/annotations/*/*/*/*.v0_gold_conll': No such file or directory
```

Comment: DON'T USE the `script` tag! Every SO question is about scripts one way or another

Answer (score 0):

That script now lives at https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/blob/main/allennlp_models/coref/tools/compile_coref_data.sh. Try the new version from that location!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the issue persists.

Comment: I suspect it's an issue with the directory you're pointing it at then. Unfortunately we can't share that data the normal way because of licensing reasons. You can get that data from https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2013T19.

Comment: Okay. Thanks again!